# How to drop the rows with duplicates and blanks in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to drop the rows if there is any duplicates or having blank value based on the subset['Column Name']

Input Data :

```
Col1      Col2

AZBC11   Ayz Ltd
APNK22   EXL Ltd
AZBC11   Ayz Ltd
         Vmware Inc
By25NZ   UHG Inc
NH55KJ   AON Interprise
```

Output Expected:

```
Col1      Col2

AZBC11   Ayz Ltd
APNK22   EXL Ltd
By25NZ   UHG Inc
NH55KJ   AON Interprise
```

**Script been using :**

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1'])
```

With the above script i can remove the duplicates but how can i update the above line so that it can remove the rows in case of duplicates or blanks based on **col1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
print(df[df["Col1"] != ""].drop_duplicates(subset=["Col1"]))
```

Prints:

```
     Col1            Col2
0  AZBC11         Ayz Ltd
1  APNK22         EXL Ltd
4  By25NZ         UHG Inc
5  NH55KJ  AON Interprise
```